# Search Java Example for a scatted 3D Graph

Tags: java, graph

I search a Library or a way to Display a Graph in Java like the picture in the attachment, have somebody a Tip for me or a Example?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [jzy3d](http://www.jzy3d.org/)

See also this [comparison](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Comparison)

If you Google for "java scatter plot library" you may find other libraries too.

Comment: Yes, i found this library too. But a searched a code example for Data input like x y z.